# Array with number of days using moment

Tags: javascript, arrays, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am trying to create an array with number of days between two dates.

The dates can be anything but i am using the following for this example.

```
Start : 11/30/2018, End: 09/30/2019
Array= [30,31,29,30....31]
```

What i am trying to do:

[image]

Here date ranges from `30 to 30` and `30-29.`

I have the following code:

```js
const start = "11/30/2018";
const end = "09/30/2019";

const dates = [];

const mstart = moment(new Date(start));
const mend = moment(new Date(end));

for (let i = 0; mstart < mend ; i++) {

    const daysInMonth = mstart.daysInMonth() + (i === 0 ? -1 : -1);
                      //mstart.daysInMonth() + (i === 0 ? -1 : 0) for the first case.

    dates.push(daysInMonth);

    mstart.add(1, 'M');
}

console.log(dates);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Issue:

The date range works for other dates as long as it's not towards the end of the month.

I need the date range to go from start date to end date. Here, it calculates the date from 30 to 29  but as soon as it goes to February it takes 28th of that month and then starts the date range from there.

How do i fix this?

Comment: I have updated the answer, check it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go about comparing the dates directly rather than by the number of days in the month. Also added in a check to make sure you capture your enddate correctly if its not the same day for start and end

```js
const start = "11/30/2018";
const end = "09/30/2019";

const dates = [];

const mstart = moment(new Date(start));
const mend = moment(new Date(end));

let i = 0;
while (1 == 1) {
  let nextStart = mstart.clone().add(i, 'M');
  let nextEnd = mstart.clone().add(i + 1, 'M') > mend ? mend : mstart.clone().add(i + 1, 'M');

  dates.push(nextEnd.diff(nextStart, 'days'));

  if (nextEnd >= mend) {
    break;
  }

  i += 1
}


console.log(dates);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work because February has 28 days but still prints 29

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the days between `startDate` and `endDate` and use `moment` to take the next day, then extract the day of the month with [moment(date).date()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/date/)... 
 Do this  until you arrive to the end.

#### Update: Add snippet:

```js
// Returns all month days.
function getDays(start, end) {
    const days = [];
    start = moment(new Date(start));
    end = moment(new Date(end));
    while (start <= end) {
        days.push(moment(start).date())
        start = moment(start).add(1, 'days');
    }
    return days;
}

// Returns the number of month days.
function getMonthDays(start, end) {
    const days = [];
    start = moment(new Date(start));
    end = moment(new Date(end));
    while (start <= end) {
        days.push(moment(start).daysInMonth())
        start = moment(start).add(1, 'M');
    }
    return days;
}
    
// console.log(getDays("11/30/2018", "09/30/2019"));
console.log(getMonthDays("11/30/2018", "09/30/2019"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: looks like it currently outputs each day separately rather than the sum difference for each monthly increment

Comment: Ah, this is what I understood.... I'm pretty sure he does not want the sum, though :-| Probably the number of days of each month of the provided range.

Comment: @V.Sambor I am literally just trying to get number of days between the 2 dates and not each and every day.

Comment: @ace23 Could you please provide an input and exactly expected output?

Comment: @V.Sambor The result is in the question itself!

Comment: @ace23 have you checked my new answer? run the snippet ... to see if it fits your request

Comment: @V.Sambor Yes i did and no it doesn't work. Compare the output to my requirement.