# Get an array with number of days

Tags: javascript, arrays, momentjs

I am trying to create an array with number of days between 2 dates.

The dates can be anything but i will be using the following:

```
Start : 11/30/2018, End: 09/30/2019
Array= [30,31,29,30....31]
```

What i am trying to achieve:

[image]

What i have tried:

```js
const start = "11/30/2018";
const end = "09/30/2019";

const dates = [];

const mstart = moment(new Date(start));
const mend = moment(new Date(end));

let i = 0;
while (1 == 1) {
  let nextStart = mstart.clone().add(i, 'M');
  let nextEnd = mstart.clone().add(i + 1, 'M') > mend ? mend : mstart.clone().add(i + 1, 'M');

  dates.push(nextEnd.diff(nextStart, 'days'));

  if (nextEnd >= mend) {
    break;
  }

  i += 1
}


console.log(dates);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

The date array ranges from `30-30` in the first few columns and `30-29` in last columns except the leap year.

The first case works. How do i make the date range from 30-29th for the second case? I tried .subtract(1, 'days') but it doesn't return the right result because i want the date range to work too instead of just subtracting a day every time.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @ponury-kostek I am trying to create an array with number of days between a date range and not just get the total number of days between 2 dates.

Comment: So do you want the days of the month? or an count of the days?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array with number of days using moment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53564275/array-with-number-of-days-using-moment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option

1. Do another check for end date checking if greater than 28
2. Add and subtract days based on that condition

```js
const start = "11/30/2018";
const end = "09/30/2019";

const dates = [];

const mstart = moment(new Date(start));
const mend = moment(new Date(end));
let nextEnd

let i = 0;
while (1 == 1) {
  let nextStart = nextEnd? (nextEnd.date() > 28 ? nextEnd.add(1, 'days') : nextEnd) : nextEnd || mstart.clone().add(i, 'M');
  nextEnd = mstart.clone().add(i + 1, 'M') > mend ? mend : mstart.clone().add(i +1, 'M');

  if(nextEnd.date() > 28){
    nextEnd.subtract(1, 'days')
  }else{
   
  }
  console.log("start-->", nextStart.format('MM/DD/YYYY'), "end--", nextEnd.format('MM/DD/YYYY'))

 

  if (nextEnd >= mend) {
    break;
  }else{
     dates.push(nextEnd.diff(nextStart, 'days'));
  }

  i += 1
}


console.log(dates)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/LXaKKY?editors=1010

Comment: Works great. Thank you much!

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI that moment has an official plugin ([it is in their documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/range/)) in regards to ranges and with it your solution would look something among these lines:

```
const Moment = require('moment');
const MomentRange = require('moment-range');
const moment = MomentRange.extendMoment(Moment);

const range = moment.range(moment(new Date("11/30/2018")), moment(new Date("09/30/2019")));
console.log(Array.from(range.by('day')).map(x => +x.format('DD')))
```

You can change the format you want to get the days in via the last `x.format('')` etc

You can see it [working here](https://repl.it/@akrion/DayRangeWithMoment)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
const start = "11/30/2018";
const end = "09/30/2019";

const dates = [];

const mstart = moment(new Date(start));
const mend = moment(new Date(end));

while (mstart.format('MM-DD-YYYY') != mend.format('MM-DD-YYYY')) {
  dates.push(mstart.format('DD'));
  mstart.add(1, 'day');
}

console.log(dates);
```

You can check it here: https://jsbin.com/lufupihabe/edit?html,js,console

Comment: This will add 1 month but that's not my requirement. I need it to add 1 month based on the start date every time. Once it reaches February, it will add 1 month based on February.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me:

```
  while (1 == 1) {
  let nextStart = mstart.clone().add(i, 'M');
  let nextEnd = mstart.clone().add(i + 1, 'M').subtract(1,'days') > mend ? mend : mstart.clone().add(i + 1, 'M').subtract(1,'days') ;
```